# Ruby: in `require': cannot load such file -- safe_yaml/load (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, rubygems, jekyll

When I want to change content of the web page, I go to my local project directory and I run two commands:

```
jekyll build
jekyll serve
```

After that, my web app is running locally on my machine. When I tried to run the above commands today, I got stuck on the first of them, because the following error appeared:

```
$ jekyll build
Traceback (most recent call last):
    5: from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:8:in `<main>'
    4: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    3: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    2: from /Users/JaroslavBezdek/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll.rb:34:in `<top (required)>'
    1: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require': cannot load such file -- safe_yaml/load (LoadError)
```

I started to look it up on the internet and found I should try to install the missing library. However, it didn't solve the problem, because the other error showed up:

```
$ gem install safe_yaml
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.
$ sudo gem install safe_yaml
Password:
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory.
```

My environment could be described as following:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]
$ gem --version
3.1.1
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.1
BuildVersion:   19B88
```

Please, could you help me, how to solve the problem?

Comment: Install RVM with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`; restart your shell; install Ruby with `rvm install 2.6.0`. [Don't](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/psa-do-not-use-system-ruby) [use](https://chrisherring.co/posts/why-you-shouldn-t-use-the-system-ruby) [system Ruby](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2014/05/15/never-use-system-ruby-ever/).

Comment: Alternatively to rvm you can use [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv).

Comment: @anothermh, thank you for your help. I tried, what you suggested. After that, I tried to build an app with `jekyll build`, but another load error showed up: `/Users/JaroslavBezdek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require': cannot load such file -- pathutil (LoadError)`. Please, do you know, how to solve this?

Comment: Is this your first time running it locally? And does your project have a Gemfile?